# Is there any optimized, reliable C++ Shunting-Yard algorithm implementation?

Tags: c++

For commercial purpose, my team decided to use a Shunting-Yard algorithm in the calculating engine, and created an sample implementation. Although we have the implementation, if there is other reliable, optimized implementation for doing it, we would seriously consider using it. Is there any? The language is C++, and the usage is for time-critical application.

Since I have at least one implementation, I am looking for open-sourced library which has the algorithm implementation. BSD-like license would be preferable.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending software meeting specific requirements – not approaches, [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185) or [algorithms](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185). Are you asking for code, or for a c++ library to use with your project? In the latter case, could you mention your license and price requirements?

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for the detailed introduction. Since I have at least one implementation, I am looking for open-sourced library which has the algorithm implementation. BSD-like license would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it on-topic. I've integrated this with your question to make it easier to spot. Good luck then!